# Hubble bubble and the shell theorem?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion

According to the Hubble bubble theory a local void could explain deviations of the Hubble constant for measurements in close vicinity to out local group compared to the global Hubble constant and perhaps as an alternative explanation to dark energy for the acceleration of the expansion of the Universe, allowing for our Universe to actually be an Einstein-de Sitter universe.

While this theory seem to be considered pretty much debunked today I'm still interested in the theory, because I can't wrap my head around how it could ever be considered as it seem to contradict the shell theorem? 
Sure the distribution of galaxies along the "walls" containing the local void wouldn't be perfectly symmetrical and the void not perfectly spherical, but are these deviations really enough to warrant such a theory?

Answer (score 0):

If an observer is inside a void (or an overdensity for that matter), the photons that are traveling toward the void/overdensity would lose/gain energy and get redshifted/blueshifted.

Comment: Okay, but why is that? What causes the red-/blueshift?

Comment: If you throw a ball up, it looses energy because it's fighting gravity. If you shoot a laser up it looses kinetic energy because of gravity. The former looses speed the latter changes frequency as a result.

Comment: Do you know what the shell theorem is and why I mentioned it in my post?

Comment: Are you talking about the shell theorm from mechanics? If not, can you elaborate? Actually can you explain more what you mean by that? Are we, as observers, in middle of this local group? If so, my argument applies.

Comment: Yes, from classical mechanics. In a symmetrical spherical shell the net gravitational force is zero at all points within the shell, so why would the light get red-/blueshifted? I get that the void would not be perfectly symmetrical, but are the imperfections really enough to cause such an effect? And also the studies I've looked at actually do assume a perfect symmetry, but they don't explain the contradiction with the shell theorem.

Comment: Because even though the net gravitational field due to a shell is zero, the falling object/photon still sees the massive sphere in front of it. Whatever is behind the falling object will not affect it, but it will experience momentum gain until it reaches the center of the sphere.

Comment: Why would that be though? I really don't see how that works out logically. If the gravitational force is zero at every point, then why would it "see the massive sphere in front of it"? It would equally see the rest of the sphere that is behind it which would cancel out the part that's in front of it. That's the whole idea of the shell theorem.

Comment: Do you see why if we were at the center of a spherical over density, the photon would experience blue shift?

Comment: Yes, but it would also experience a net gravitational force towards the center of mass of the mass within a sphere of radius r, where r is the distance from the center to the photon.

Comment: It suddenly clicked for me and I understand now. I was thinking about it in the wrong way first. Thank you for your time.